# How to reference a global variable in a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to use some variables through the code, of course if the variable is global, it's ok. But I want to use functions, so I could just pass some parameters in my future work.

For example, this code is throwing an error:

```
def fun1():
  print a_variable

def fun2(a_variable='hello, world'):
  fun1()

fun2('hello, world')
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-31e8e239671e> in <module>()
      5   fun1()
      6 
----> 7 fun2('hello, world')

<ipython-input-42-31e8e239671e> in fun2(a_variable)
      3 
      4 def fun2(a_variable='hello, world'):
----> 5   fun1()
      6 
      7 fun2('hello, world')

<ipython-input-42-31e8e239671e> in fun1()
      1 def fun1():
----> 2   print a_variable
      3 
      4 def fun2(a_variable='hello, world'):
      5   fun1()

NameError: global name 'a_variable' is not defined
```

Since `a_variable` is valid in `fun2`, how come `fun1` is not? How can I resolve this? I don't want to add additional parameters to `fun1`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Answer (score 1):

In python there's a simple statement to make variables global. However, first you need to change the name of the variable in your parameter-list of `fun2()`. After this change you can insert the `global`-statement:

```
def fun2(a='hello, world'):
    global a_variable # declaration
    a_variable = a # definition
    fun1()
```

If you don't change the parameter-list you get another error: `'a_variable' is local and global`.

Comment: Hi, thanks. This works. But I don't really like this. Because this bring a global variable but in fact 'a_variable' just need to be "global" in the namespace of "fun2".

Comment: maybe you should put the line `global a_variable` outside of any function (but still before the first function call). Then you don't need to call `fun2` to make the variable global.

Comment: ok, `global a_variable` outside a function doesn't do anything in this case. it probably doesn't work because inside the `fun2`- function the variable is interpreted as local, as long as you don't explicity tell the interpreter to refer it to the global variable. In other words: you probably need the `global a_variable` statement inside `fun2()`.